# Keep Tags when reading from raw text file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, fgets

I have a simple text file.  The content has xml tags.  The issue with that is some of the elements don't have closing tags.

I am able to read the file in line by line, however the tags are missing when I echo back what was read.

Sample File Content.

```
<SOL>
<Name> JJ Evans
<Address> 1010 Good Times Lane
</Sol>
```

When I read this file, line by line and echo out the output I get:

```
JJ Evans
1010 Good Times Lane
```

I need the output to be:

```
<SOL>
<Name> JJ Evans
<Address> 1010 Good Times Lane
</Sol>
```

And help resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you echoing such that the output is missing the tags? In the browser or the PHP command line?

Comment: in such situations, it would really be easier to point our issues, if you could post any code sample that you are, currently, using. by the looks of it, it seems that your `read` function is a bit messed up, somewhere. are you using some custom code for reading the file, instead of `file_get_contents` or some variant, directly?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) on each line, it won't let the browser parse the tags. Also if you don't have any particular need to read the file line-by-line, you better stick with [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), just call `htmlentities(file_get_contents('sample.xml'))` and you'll make the job even easier.